# What simple offline GUI database should I use for this application?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, windows

I am looking an open source application. Application should have :

```
  * database support ( create two or three table )
  * GUI ( what I have created should be seen )
```

Example :

```
Assume that I have created a table ;

       X_table  :          |  A  | B  | C | D |

 After creating  table, I am loading data 
                           |  A  |  B   | C  | D  |
                           |  1  |  11  | b  | f  |   -
                           |  3  |  12  | a  | o  |   - data 
                           |  4  |  13  | r  | o  |   -

    When I am opening application not for loading data, I want see data in graphical 
 interface.

   One day, I want modify existing data. I can just clicking the place then add new 
 data

    Assume I want change 12. I am clicking that position and then writing new data
                           |  A  |  B   | C  | D  |
                           |  -  |  --  | -  | -  |   -
                           |  3  |  19  | a  | o  |   - data 
                           |  -  |  --  | -  | -  |   -
```

Are there any open source application which have above feature ?

Application can be so simple,

```
 * no internet connection
 * support only one database 
 * static table creation ( once created never changed )
```

Application can be run Ubuntu 12.04 and/or Windows.

In other words, I am wanting database viewer and editor.

EDIT:

I should load pdf file, image etc. or give path of the file to the application.

This [link](http://www.vbseo.com/attachments/f67/4421d1215407244-sitemap-cronjob-error-mysql-server-has-gone-away-vbulletin-options-hondaswap-forums-vbulletin-admin-control-panel_1215407248589.png) can be reference to my question . ( Interface should be like this, just a list )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Libre-office Base](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/base/) sounds like what your after, runs on Windows and Linux, has a GUI, just an alternate to MS Access really.

Edit:

Heres me clicking around adding data straight into the table.
[image]

Comment: How can I add data interactively to the database ? Assume I want add one new data to field of the table without using command. How can I do that ? ( just click to field then add/modify data to here )

Comment: it's all GUI driven, so yes just click and add text to a table that you created.

Comment: I could not do that. Do I need any plugin ? I know it is GUI driven but its job is only showing what data stored in database. ( I think )

Comment: Yes you can edit the table directly. as I show in edit.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure your system is up-to-date.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update
```

> Firebird is a relational database offering many ANSI SQL standard
>   features that runs on Linux, Windows, and a variety of Unix platforms.
>   Firebird offers excellent concurrency, high performance, and powerful
>   language support for stored procedures and triggers.

Install Firebird Database on Ubuntu

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install firebird2.1-classic
```

<sup>Source: [ubuntugeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/firebird-database-setup-on-ubuntu-linux.html)</sup>

<sup>Source: [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird2.1)</sup>

> The MySQL database has become the world's most popular open source
>   database because of its high performance, high reliability and ease of
>   use. It is also the database of choice for a new generation of
>   applications built on the LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP / Perl
>   / Python.) Many of the world's largest and fastest-growing
>   organizations including Facebook, Google, Adobe, Alcatel Lucent and
>   Zappos rely on MySQL to save time and money powering their high-volume
>   Web sites, business-critical systems and packaged software.
>
> MySQL runs on more than 20 platforms including Linux, Windows, Mac OS,
>   Solaris, IBM AIX, giving you the kind of flexibility that puts you in
>   control. Whether you're new to database technology or an experienced
>   developer or DBA, MySQL offers a comprehensive range of database
>   tools, support, training and consulting services to make you
>   successful.

To install it

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

<sup>Source: [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/)</sup>

MySQL is not just for writing queries, it a full featured Database application.

But if you want something simple, just use LibreOffice Base, its included in the libreoffice suite that installs when you install Ubuntu.  Or you can use the latest OpenOffice Base  To do so

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install openoffice.org-base
```

Comment: But, your recommendation is so complicated. I am wanting an application which can I just see and load data, not writing query. Query can be done via terminal which I prefer. If Mysql has an option like closing query window, can you say me how ? Thanks for replay

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something similar to MS-Acess or Filemaker, then:

[Kexi](http://www.kexi-project.org/) [image: Install Kexi]

Kexi is an integrated data management application by KDE, designed to fill the gap between spreadsheets and database solutions requiring more sophisticated development. Kexi can be used for designing and implementing databases, data inserting and processing, and performing queries.

The impetus for developing Kexi came from a noticeable lack of applications having the features of Microsoft Access, FoxPro, Oracle Forms or FileMaker while at the same time being powerful, inexpensive, open-standards-driven and sufficiently portable.
The proprietary version of Kexi 1.x

Kexi is a component of Calligra Suite. It works under Linux/Unix, Mac OS X (using Fink), Solaris, and the Microsoft Windows (using KDE on Windows) operating systems. Kexi application and libraries is available under the LGPL. User and developer documentation is available under the GFDL.

(source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexi))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To meet your needs I recommend mySQL with mySQL workbench (also from the mysql folks).
It it probably the world's most used open source SQL database and it is supported by Sun/Oracle.

You get command line options:

[image]

plus a gui to both let see you data:

[image]

and a gui to view the models:

[image]